# The amount of Pixels required for a 5x2,5m billboard

Tags: print-design, resolution, file-size, billboard

I as an amateur have been asked to supply a file size of above 12MB for a 5x2,5m billboard, Firstly I have a Canon 600D that I believe has a max file size of about 6,4MB and 2ndly how does one achieve a higher MB for this exercise?

Answer (score 0):

> as an amateur have been asked to supply a file size of above 12MB

Oh my... Well, the bad news is that the amateur was the person that asked you that. Some XXMb, as a unit of size, has **no** sense at all.

(The only case is when you have very limited bandwidth, for example a webpage with a lot of traffic limits you on the size of the images you can upload, and converts them, sometimes with some Kb, kilobytes, as a unit)

There is a chance you have being asked to provide a file of above 12 **Megapixels** or Mpx. Your camera has 18 Mpx.